# I would like to use VBA in excel to change the format of the data I am working with to match the system I am loading to

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

In essence I have a data source that comes in a specific format. I need to come up with an automated process in excel that would format this data accordingly.

**The current state of the data looks like this:**
[image]

**The future state I would like to get to with this data would look like this:**
[image]

Just to be clear the A0220 in the first picture stands for February 2020 actual. The first two digits after the letter denote month.

Thus far, I have tried to bridge my knowledge gap by taking what I know about 'Offsets & Positioning' & manually recording a macro that can transpose data.

If we can focus on how to move the data first. I was thinking of blending something like this:

Code:

```
Sub Transposeforsystemload()

Selection.Copy

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True


End Sub
```

Ron Rosenfeld has provided a wonderful solution to this problem (see his post in the answers below). However due to the fact that I am operating on excel professional 2016; two of the critical functions are not available for me apply.

The two are:

Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Series", "Column1.2"}),

&

Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(2), {"Month", "Yr"}),

If anyone has any alternatives, to these functions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Comment: I would like to emphasize that we here do not like solving riddles. Please, at lease, edit your question and try explaining **in words** based on what you want transforming your existing data.

Comment: @FaneDuru, Thanks for your guidance. This is the first time I have used/posted to StackOverflow and was not really sure how it worked. I am currently editing the post to incorporate what I have tried thus far. As well as why this end state is important. I apologize if it sounded like i was trying to pose a riddle. I didnt want any information that I added to cause confusion or bias. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about your downvotes on first question, but I think this is because your question is somewhat vague and not clear where you're stuck. Your suggested code does not help your question. I'm happy to help, but first I would like to suggest that you loop through the cells of your input data(make a `Range`) and collect them based on Letter and Year and start writing them to a new worksheet. I suggest that you don't use copy, offset, select, paste etc. Come back with your code that you tried.

Comment: @GisMofx Thank you for the guidance. This is my first step towards developing this skill. Your comment has really helped me understand the proper way to create the code. Up until this point I was just trying to find a solution, by the path of least resistance. I will research making a range and applying functions to isolate the parts of the string I want and will edit my question. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365). One advantage over VBA/native Excel is a function which allows creating a Pivot table without aggregating the results.

To do this,

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2 of the code.
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Read table into query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//Demote the headers to the data area
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),

//Remove first column as not needed
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Demoted Headers",{"Column1"}),

//Transpose the table
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),

//set data types
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transposed Table",{{"Column2", Currency.Type}}),

//Split column by change from letter to digit to get the Series (all letters) and monthYear (four digits
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = 
        Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Column1", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Series", "Column1.2"}),

//Split the four digits into month number and year number
    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Character Transition", "Column1.2", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(2), {"Month", "Yr"}),

//Create Series/Year row label by combining some of the previous splits
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Position", "Series/Year", each [Series] & "20" & [Yr]),

//Create monthName column by creating date from year and month
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "monthName", each 
        Text.Start(Date.MonthName(#date(Number.FromText([Yr])+2000,Number.FromText([Month]),1)),3)),

//Sort by month number to get into proper order, then remove that column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom1",{{"Month", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Series", "Month"}),

//PIvot by Month Name and don't aggregate
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[monthName]), "monthName", "Column2"),

//Remove the Yr column as it was only there to assure proper sorting of the results
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Yr"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , I had never used power query until you posed this answer. You have opened up a whole new realm of thought for me. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have 3 types of data in your source table (Axx20, Fxx20, Axx21), which follow the same pattern:

- First a letter (A or F)
- Then two digits for the month (from 01 to 12)
- And finally two digits for the year (20 for 2020, 21 for 2021, and so on I guess)

You could loop through your source table, then use functions like `Left`, `Middle` and `Right` to split your original data into 2 variables composed of `letter + year` and `month`.

Then based on the value of this variables, you can paste amounts in the destination table at their correction position. Here is a guide on how these functions work and how to code them: [Guide VBA Left / Middle / Right](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-left-right-mid/). Furthermore, how to create loops on ranges [Looping through defined range](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html).